# What is wrong with this MySQL code?

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE EVENT CestaTicket
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 SECOND
DO 
BEGIN    
 DECLARE var INT;
 DECLARE contador INT; 
 DECLARE valor FLOAT; 
 SET contador=0;
 SET var=0;
 SET valor=0;
 WHILE (var<(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IdEmpleado) FROM asistencia WHERE (Asistio=1 AND (Fecha BETWEEN (Now() AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY))))))
   SELECT COUNT(IdEmpleado) INTO contador FROM asistencia 
   WHERE (IdEmpleado=var AND Fecha BETWEEN (Now() AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)));

      IF (contador>0)      
      SET valor = contador*0.95*95;      
      INSERT INTO reporte (Emision,Descripcion,Accion,IdEmpleado) 
      VALUES (Now(),CONCAT('El monto asignado para el empleado es: ',CAST(valor AS VARCHAR(30))),'Monto CestaTicket',var);
  END IF;
      var = var + 1;        
  END WHILE;

END |

DELIMITER ;
`
```

I was wondering if someone could help me by telling me what's wrong with the code, I'm new to MySQL sentences, so please be patient with me!

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong? But please don't say "it doesn't work", it's not helpful

Comment: I think what's wrong with my code is this part           SELECT COUNT(IdEmpleado) INTO contador FROM asistencia 
   WHERE (IdEmpleado=var AND Fecha BETWEEN (Now() AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)));

Comment: @Guayo You have to tell us *why* you think it is wrong, not *what* you think is wrong.

Comment: Use "DELIMITER |;" instead of "DELIMITER |"                    incase you are referring to this error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')))) SELECT COUNT(IdEmpleado) INTO contador FROM asistencia WHERE (IdEm' at line 11"

Comment: @srikanth That can be an answer

Comment: @Guayo:close this by marking the correct answer.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use "DELIMITER |;" instead of "DELIMITER |" incase you are referring to this error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')))) SELECT COUNT(IdEmpleado) INTO contador FROM asistencia WHERE (IdEm' at line 11"